# JSF composite components. How do I pass top-level f:facet to underlying component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

For a long time I had one composite component defined and used as follows:

```
<!-- simple -->
<composite:interface>
  <composite:facet name="header"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
  <composite:renderFacet name="header"/>
</composite:implementation>

<xyz:simple>
  <f:facet name="header">
    test
  </f:facet>
</xyz:simple>
```

Now I want to reuse it in another component and pass it's facet value to underlying component:

```
<!-- advanced -->
<composite:interface>
  <composite:facet name="header"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
  <!-- some stuff -->
  <xyz:helper>
    <composite:insertFacet name="header"/>  
  </xyz:helper>
</composite:implementation>

<xyz:advanced>
  <f:facet name="header">
    test 2
  </f:facet>
</xyz:advanced>
```

And I get no output. Any ideas?